# Create a node from app Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen that to access data from the Firebase database, we need to access a node. 
Is it possible to create a node from the app and keep adding information there instead of having to create a node before?

This is so users can create their own node and access it directly.

Comment: Firebase stores values at specific paths. You don't have to pre-create the paths, they are created as you put values at them (and removed when you remove the values). It sounds like you're having problem with a specific piece of code. In that case, please share the minimal code that reproduces the problem. That will make it a lot easier to offer concrete help.